# What are the right tools for me for indexing and processing big data?

Tags: hadoop, indexing, mapreduce

I'm trying to index and store big data, and I'm a bit confused on what tools to use. Let me start by saying I'm a novice here and have only theoretical knowledge on the topic. I want to:

1) use Hadoop (definitely)

2) extract log data from flat files using three different PCs

3) transform the data to structured form and load in HDFS for indexing and mapreduce.

My questions are:

a) In trying to index three fields, is it possible to map-index-map-index-map-index-reduce? if not, how is indexing done? If possible to explain in sequence (e.g index-map-reduce)

b) What are the right tools to use from extraction to storage?

c) Can Hadoop be used for a simple search, or another tool such as lucene/solr must be used?

d) Must data be converted into structured form, e.g using PDI, before going through the MapReduce phase?

Comment: Big topic, no "simple" answers.  SUGGESTION: Google: Hadoop open source analytics

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are looking to index some data stored in hadoop then Cloudera Search is the perfect use case for you. Link: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-search/v1-latest/Cloudera-Search-User-Guide/csug_introducing.html

I currently use it at Goibibo.com for indexing log data. You can use it for indexing data in real time as well as in map reduce mode. Internally it uses Solr to index and perfectly fits your use case. You can also expose the indexed collections through Hue.

Comment: The files are not stored in hadoop. I'm trying to transfer from flat file to hadoop. What's the best tool for this? Also, is the method of indexing i described possible?

Comment: Since you are transferring the files to hadoop, you can either index the files on the fly (using Flume) or index them in mapreduce mode. Just read about cloudera search once and you will know.

Comment: Thank you so much for this info. I think cloudera search is just what I need, but I want to be clear on something; After installing Cloudera search, do I need to install any other tool to get the task done? do I need to install hadoop again, ETL tool, solr, etc? Also, can you please tell me the role that each of these tools will be playing, from extracting the data from the source file, to search after processing.

Comment: See if you have Hadoop installed you don't need anything extra. If you want to index logs in real time then you would need Flume, else it is not required. Now Hue is another tool which can be useful if you want to expose it through a UI. Again that is a not a necessity.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using elastic search or solar for indexing the big data.